# Structuring an MVC project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I find the way of "having controller/view in same project, all model in separate class library" not intuitive to me. I prefer to have it vertically, i.e. having related controllers/views/view model in separate projects.

So I look up the internet and find that some (not many) people are using the area feature, but I find it a pain when it comes to do routing.

So why can't I put controller/views/view models as separate projects instead of area? Am I not able to do that or does that decrease performance so nobody uses it?

Answer (score 2):

You **can** structure the solution however you want. Everything is configurable to work the way you want. Furthermore, the way you structure your solution should have no effect on performance.

It's going to be much more straightforward to structure the solution the idiomatic, default way. Other users of MVC are already familiar with the default way, which makes for easy collaboration. Even if you feel another structure is better - even if it **is** better - you're still going to greatly benefit from tolerating the default structure.

Comment: [Convention over Configuration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_configuration)--the backbone of MVC, given the hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

You actually can move the views model and controllers to the other projects.

It is not something available out of the box.

You would need to create your own implementation of few MVC infrastructure classes like: `ViewEngine`, controller factory and etc. I wouldn't recommend going this way as you would have really hard time migrating your project to new versions of ASP.NET MVC and the classes which Microsoft supplies are well tested and optimized.